# Matlab Processing Sequentially Numbered Images

Tags: matlab

I have nearly 1000 images started as 
   img0.png, img1.png, img3.png, ..., img1000.png.
   I am using MatLab and my code is following:

```
    imageNames = dir(fullfile(workingDir,'*.png'));
```

So **imageNames** struct contains as following

img0.png

img1.png

img10.png

img100.png
   .......

**But I want**

img0.png

img1.png

img2.png
   .......

Is this possible to do programmatically in MatLab?

Regards

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10959-sort-nat--natural-order-sort) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47434-natural-order-filename-sort) - both on Matlab's Fileexchange about "Natural Order Filename Sort".

Comment: Thanks but I understood they explain how MATLAB react to the file in the sort order. I needed more of a like a programmatic code to change first 100 image into format like 00x, I am still searching

Comment: What are you trying to do? Renaming those files?

Comment: Exactly; how many files do I have 1000 then I 'll have to make first image img1 as img0001, img2 as img0002 and so on. I don't know other way to sort appropriately

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, but I am using matlab, does operating system make difference? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to convert the filenames like you've said in your comment. You can use [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to get a list of new filenames corresponding to the old filenames.

```
newnames = regexprep({imageNames.name},'(img)(\d*)(\.png)','$1${sprintf(''%04d'', $2)}$3')
```

Essentially, this pulls out the numeric part of each filename, and runs this through [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to zero pad it as you suggested (4 digit zero-padding).

If you want to re-save the images with these new names, you can do that simply in a loop.

```
for k = 1:numel(imageNames);
    movefile(imageNames(k).name, newnames{k});
end
```

If you want, you can also sort the `newnames` variable and it will sort naturally now.

```
[values, sortinds] = sort(newnames);
sortedNames = imageNames(sortinds);
```

Comment: Why waste time reading in the image file instead of using [`movefile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html) to rename?

Comment: @excaza good point. Answer has been updated.

Comment: newnames = regexprep({imageNames.name},'(img)(\d*)(\.png)','$1${sprintf(''%04d'', $2)}$3') lines give errors

Comment: @AhmetTavli what is the error that you are seeing?